# Python/SQL Insert Into Missing Expression

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

Using Python, trying to write a row of values into a SQL table. The values (n=27) are a mix of data types (text, int, date) and using a custom built function to execute the transaction to the SQL table. I have a list of fields:

```
oracleFieldsList = ["REQ_ID", "MEMBER_ID", "DATA_ID", "DTTM_REQ", "DTTM_UPD", "DESCR_PROJECTION", "DESCR_LOCATION", "MEDIA_TRANSFER",
"FILE_FORMAT", "TAX_SUPPORTED", "REQ_NOTES", "USER_PROJECT", "DTTM_STAFF", "STAFF_ID", "DTTM_DELIVER", "FILE_SIZE", "SIZE_TYPE",
"NO_FILES", "DTTM_CANCEL", "CANCEL_BY_ID", "DWNLD_URL", "LABOR_HOURS", "LABOR_TOTAL", "MEDIA_QUANT", "MEDIA_TOTAL", "INVOICE_DATE", "ADMIN_ID"]
oracle_fields = ",".join(oracleFieldsList)
```

and a list of variables storing values for the one row:

```
entryValuesList = [str(REQ_ID), MEMBER_ID, DATA_ID, str(DTTM_REQ), str(DTTM_UPD), str(DESCR_PROJECTION), DESCR_LOCATION, MEDIA_TRANSFER,
str(FILE_FORMAT), TAX_SUPPORTED, REQ_NOTES, str(USER_PROJECT), DTTM_STAFF, STAFF_ID, DTTM_DELIVER, FILE_SIZE, SIZE_TYPE,
NO_FILES, DTTM_CANCEL, CANCEL_BY_ID, DWNLD_URL, LABOR_HOURS, LABOR_TOTAL, MEDIA_QUANT, MEDIA_TOTAL, INVOICE_DATE, ADMIN_ID]
entry_values = ",".join(entryValuesList)
```

and then execute the transaction with:

```
cmd = "INSERT INTO PERSONS (" + oracle_fields + """) VALUES\
        (""" + entry_values + ")"

def updateDatabase(query):
    try:    
        import cx_Oracle
        print(query)

        #submit query
        connstr = 'XXXXXXX'
        conn = cx_Oracle.connect('XX', 'XXX', connstr)
        curs = conn.cursor()
        curs.execute(query)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

updateDatabase(cmd)
```

I keep getting the "ORA-00936: missing expression" or the "ORA-00917: missing comma"

I've double-checked for missing commas, unended parens, etc, and have not seen anything obvious causing this error. Any insight would be appreciated.

Google, trial/error, reading other posts, etc.

Comment: The values aren't wrapped in single-quotes, e.g. `VALUES('foo', 'bar', ...)`. Print `cmd` and it will be obvious. Take a look at the INSERT statement syntax: https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj40774.html

Comment: I have a print (cmd) statement in the code so I review it each run, but again, don't see anything obvious to cause the error:

(23288,,,2023-07-19 16:53:56.471999884,2023-07-19 16:53:56.471999884,'','14SMJ5515, 15SUB4000','Network Transfer (FTP)','ZLAS',0,'','Site analysis for tax proposal.',,,,,'',,'',,'',,,,,,)

Comment: So the string values _are_ wrapped in single-quotes? That isn't obvious from the question. It will be helpful to have the code which produces each error.

Comment: I added in the function. The call produces the SQL error.

Comment: You need to wrap the datetimes as well. Based on your comment, it just shows `(23288,,,2023-07-19 16:53:56.471999884,2023-07-19 16:53:56.471999884,` etc.. but should be `(23288,,,'2023-07-19 16:53:56.471999884','2023-07-19 16:53:56.471999884',` etc.

Comment: @chrisbyte even if I replace the date values with two single quotes to pass the string into the cmd, I still get the missing expression error.

Comment: We really need the value of `cmd` in order to help here. There's a syntax error here which is specific to the data.

Comment: cmd is: 

"INSERT INTO PERSONS (REQ_ID,MEMBER_ID,DATA_ID,DTTM_REQ,DTTM_UPD,DESCR_PROJECTION,DESCR_LOCATION,MEDIA_TRANSFER,FILE_FORMAT,TAX_SUPPORTED,REQ_NOTES,USER_PROJECT,DTTM_STAFF,STAFF_ID,DTTM_DELIVER,FILE_SIZE,SIZE_TYPE,NO_FILES,DTTM_CANCEL,CANCEL_BY_ID,DWNLD_URL,LABOR_HOURS,LABOR_TOTAL,MEDIA_QUANT,MEDIA_TOTAL,INVOICE_DATE,ADMIN_ID) VALUES        (23288,'',2643,2023-07-19 16:53:56.471999884,2023-07-19 16:53:56.471999884,'','14SMJ5515, 15SUB4000','Network Transfer (FTP)','ZLAS',0,'','Site analysis for tax proposal.','',,'',,'',,'',,'',,,,,,)"

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly how you got the cmd example in your comments, but when I run your code with some simple lines I don't get the final statement wrapped in commas for the string columns.

(This is a simplified example using your code as a start)

```
REQ_ID = 23288
MEMBER_ID = ""
MEDIA_TRANSFER = "Network Transfer (FTP)"

oracleFieldsList = ["REQ_ID", "MEMBER_ID", "MEDIA_TRANSFER"]
entryValuesList = [str(REQ_ID), MEMBER_ID, MEDIA_TRANSFER]

oracle_fields = ",".join(oracleFieldsList)
entry_values = ",".join(entryValuesList)

cmd = "INSERT INTO PERSONS (" + oracle_fields + """) VALUES (""" + entry_values + ")"

print(cmd)
# INSERT INTO PERSONS (REQ_ID,MEMBER_ID,MEDIA_TRANSFER) VALUES (23288,,Network Transfer (FTP))
```

What you are after is something like this?

```
entry_values = str(entryValuesList).strip("[]")

cmd = "INSERT INTO PERSONS (" + oracle_fields + """) VALUES (""" + entry_values + ")"

print(cmd)
# INSERT INTO PERSONS (REQ_ID,MEMBER_ID,MEDIA_TRANSFER,TAX_SUPPORTED) VALUES ('23288', '', 'Network Transfer (FTP)', 0)
```

Comment: INSERT INTO PERSONS (REQ_ID,MEMBER_ID,DATA_ID,DTTM_REQ,DTTM_UPD,DESCR_PROJECTION,DESCR_LOCATION,MEDIA_TRANSFER,FILE_FORMAT,TAX_SUPPORTED,REQ_NOTES,USER_PROJECT,DTTM_STAFF,STAFF_ID,DTTM_DELIVER,FILE_SIZE,SIZE_TYPE,NO_FILES,DTTM_CANCEL,CANCEL_BY_ID,DWNLD_URL,LABOR_HOURS,LABOR_TOTAL,MEDIA_QUANT,MEDIA_TOTAL,INVOICE_DATE,ADMIN_ID) VALUES        ('23288', None, '2643', '2023-07-19 16:53:56.471999884', '2023-07-19 16:53:56.471999884', '', '14SMJ5515, 15SUB4000', 'Network Transfer (FTP)', 'ZLAS', '0', '', 'Site analysis for tax proposal.', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')

Comment: That's what the new cmd looks like, but the new error is 'ORA-00984: column not allowed here'

Comment: Is this value `'14SMJ5515, 15SUB4000'` supposed to be two values? Having an extra column name in the INSERT is a common cause of ORA-00984.

Comment: That value is intended to be that way. It's a list to be used in processing downstream, but need to enclose the multivalues in quotes.

Comment: `None` isn't a keyword or function, so the parser rejects it as a misplaced column name.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet would be to use bind variables. This eliminates potential security issues (sql injection) and eliminates issues with quoting, type conversions, etc. Using a simplified example:

```py
fields_list = ["REQ_ID", "MEMBER_ID", "INVOICE_DATE"]
oracle_fields = ",".join(fields_list)

data = [2154, 1234, datetime.date.today()]
oracle_binds = ",".join(f":{i + 1}" for i in range(len(data)))
cmd = f"INSERT INTO PERSONS ({oracle_fields}) values {oracle_binds})"
cursor.execute(cmd, data)
```